How to Request Volume per Resource on Downstream Services using Datadog APIs?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to extract request volume per resource on downstream services. I am considering using Datadog for this purpose. Does Datadog provide APIs that allow for extracting request volume per resource on downstream services? If so, could someone guide me on how to implement this or provide any relevant documentation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
